# FATAL: database "dbName/" does not exist

Tags: spring, hibernate, java-8, tomcat8

I am using Spring 4.3.9, Hibernate 5.4.1 with PostgresQL 9.3.

When I start tomcat container using `./catalina.sh run`. I get below error in the log file.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "emgda/" does not exist
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2559)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.<init>(QueryExecutorImpl.java:133)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:250)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
```

Though the database along with data exists. Below are the configurations.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

     <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
         <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
         <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.230:5432/emgda/"/>
         <property name="user" value="user"/>
         <property name="password" value="some_password"/>
         <property name="minPoolSize" value="20"/>
         <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50"/>
         <property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="false"/>
         <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="3"/>
         <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="300"/>
         <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true"/>
     </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path">ehcache.xml</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.emg.server.db.Apps</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="emgDaoSupport" class="com.emg.server.db.EMGDaoSupport">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>  

</beans>
```

Comment: Remove the trailing `/` at the end of your JDBC URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove last "/" on `jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.230:5432/emgda/`,